# How can I fix hollow PVC pipes to wooden boards (MDF) to make a table?

Tags: carpentry

I have some PVC pipes (hollow) and Medium-density fibreboard (MDF) boards. I'd like to make a small table with these, using 4 PVC pipes as the "legs" of the table. But I am unsure how to fix the PVC pipes to the MDF boards elegantly (in a manner that none of the screws or attachments are easily visible on the PVC tube) and securely.

As I only know how to use a drill and saw, I'd prefer a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get caps for many diameters of pvc tube.

Screw and glue the caps to the table then push the legs on. Stability will depend on height, but the legs could be glued to the caps...

Comment: Do you mean these kind of [PVC caps](https://www.amazon.com/PVC-Caps/s?k=PVC+Caps)?

Comment: There are many designs - use what works for you.

Comment: perhaps these https://www.amazon.com/PVC-Table-Furniture-Grade-White/dp/B00F6N0CO0/ref=sr_1_22